# move error from link-time to compile-time

Tags: c++, hyperlink, copy-constructor, compile-time

I declare a class's `copy-ctor` and `operator=` `private` to make its objects un-copyable, and don't provide definitions for them both. So if the class's `friends` invokes `copying behavior` on these objects, a `link-time` error would occur, right?

```
class A
{
    public:
        ...

    private:
        A(const &a);
        A& operator=(const &a);  //just declarations, no definitions
};
```

But in order to move the error from `link-time` to `compile-time`, I learned from a book that I can do this:

```
class UnCopyable
{
    public:
        ...

    private:
        Uncopyable(const &u);
        Uncopyable& operator=(const &u);  //also no definitions
};
```

then make `A` inherit `Uncopyable`,

```
class A: private Uncopyable
{
    ...
};
```

And it says in the book, if someone invokes copying on `A`, then `A` should call `Uncopyable`'s copying counterparts first, but `Uncopyable`'s `copy-ctor` and `operator=` are private, so this will fail and error will rise, which occur in `compile-time`.

My question is why would that occur in `compile-time`?

Comment: Note that by definition both the class and its friends are tightly coupled, and the implementors of all them should be aware that the class is non-copyable. The lack of definition serves as a safe net, but I would not worry too much into making it a compile time error. The approach is *free* (has no cost) in most cases, but beware that in the event of multiple inheritance from non-copyable objects, the compiler might not be able to apply the empty base optimization for all bases (i.e. inheriting from `UnCopyable` can increase the size of your objects).

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, by empty base optimization, you mean?

Comment: Empty base optimization means that in the example above, whether you inherit from `Uncopyable` or not, the size of `A` is not changed. `Uncopyable` is *empty* (has no members), and while every *object* in the language must have a size, the space for the `Uncopyable` object within `A` can be optimized (Consider `B` to be `A` without the inheritance from `Uncopyable`: `sizeof(B) + sizeof(Uncopyable) <= sizeof(A)`. When *empty-base-optimization is in use, `sizeof(B) == sizeof(A)`, even though `sizeof(Uncopyable) != 0`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because violations of the semantics of the language are compile-time errors, whereas link-time errors are errors that result from a function being declared but the linker cannot find a definition for it.

In other words, a linker error means your program is a valid C++ program and has gotten to the linking stage where the linker is just patching up references to functions in other compilation units (since the compiler only considers one compilation unit at a time) but it has searched everywhere and can't find a definition. A compile-time error means your program violates the rules of C++ somehow.

**However**, you're a little incorrect in your assumption. Making the `operator=` `private` *will* cause a compile time error for people who try to assign those objects. The only time you'll get a linker error is when a function that has access to that class's private functions (e.g. a `friend` function or member function) *then* you'll get a linker error.